# how to get today's date less 18 years

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

What is the correct way to get date of 18 years ago from today's Date in Swift3?

In Swift2, I had

```
let startingDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -600000000)
```

Comment: How did you use ```Date``` in Swift 2? ```Date``` came in Swift 3 only. You should have used ```NSDate```.

Comment: Correct.  The autoformatter for Swift3 changed my code and I'd forgotten to use NSDate()

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want date with 18 year less you can use Calendar unit year for that.

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: Date())
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it throws an error. "Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'Date'" on Date()

Comment: Are you using some beta xcode 8? Because on final version it is working for me.

Comment: No.  It's the official release of XCode8.  I found the problem though.  I had an old helper class in my code called Date().  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Welcome mate :)